# Deployment wont generate ttf files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment, installation, sfml

When i deploy my project, a game made in SFML with C# VS2012 Professional, the content in my game will get generated into .deploy files, however, the ttf files for fonts will not get generated. So im getting an error when i try to install and play my game.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the font is missing in the folder when i have deployed the project and generated a folder with .deploy files.

To load a ttf file in SFML, is simply as this:

```
Font myFont = new Font(@"Content\arial.ttf");
```

But its missing when i publish it.

So how do i solve it?
Should i find the arial.ttf file in the computer? Because all computers have arial.ttf.
If so, then what is the destination to get that ttf file?

Or is it possible to somehow make the VS2012 create the ttf file as a .deploy like it does with textures and sounds?

I hope somebody can solve it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, by default some font files are not including during Publish

- .eot
- .json
- .ttf
- .woff

This is because their **build action** is set to **None**, this is by default. You must go to the affected file's properties and set it from "None" to "Content".

[image]

This is how I solved it (not by manually dragging the files as some may suggest)

Credits goes to this guy: http://edsykes.blogspot.com/2012/09/aspnet-build-actions-with-ttf-eot-and.html